# Pagination not working on custom post type archive

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, custom-post-type-archives

The pagination is not working. In settings > reading I have set '3' posts for blog pages show at most. On my custom post type archive page, I have 9 posts showing and I have this code. Not sure what I am missing to show the pagination, can someone help?

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( 

    array( 
        'post_type' => 'which_ev',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'category_name' => 'which-ev',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tag__not_in' => array(11, 12),
    ));

    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="featured-post" onclick="location.href='<?php the_permalink();?>';">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>" class="post-image">
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php 
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        $attachment_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
                        echo '<link rel="preload" as="image" href="' . esc_attr( $attachment_image ) . '">';    
                    } 
                ?>
                <div class="post-intro">
                    <span class="post-category">
                        Which EV?
                    </span>
                    <h2 class="post-title">
                        <?php the_title();?>
                    </h2>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="main-btn"> Read The Story <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/images/evee-01.svg"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile;
            if (  $loop->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
            <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Previous', 'domain' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Next <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'domain' ) ); ?></div>
            </div>

    <?php endif;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: is this a custom post type archive, or is it a page template that lists custom post types pretending to be an archive? Using `$loop = new WP_Query( ` to list the posts carries lots of downsides, pagination breaking being the first most encounter, but if this is an actual custom post type archive then the fix is trivial, use the `pre_get_posts` to modify the query, rather than creating a second query

Comment: Also be aware that `tag__not_in` is a _very_ slow option, and you should never set `posts_per_page` to `-1` _( how are you meant to have a page 2 of the archive if your archive displays everything all at once? )_, this is why you're getting 9 posts rather than 3 because there are 9 total posts.

Comment: this is a custom post type archive named 'archive-which_ev.php' i needed a way to have three separate sections displaying posts with specific tags. the first section to have only 1 'featured' post, the second section to have 3 'sub features' and the last one to display all except the posts with those tags in this section with the pagination

Comment: that last part can be done with a standard post loop and using `pre_get_posts`, a `new WP_Query` is unnecessary and requires lots of additional steps to resolve the problems it causes. `WP_Query` is great for when you want to show something as a special secondary thing in addition, like a sidebar, or a featured area, but you shouldn't use it to change the primary/main list of posts

Comment: ok good to know! i used the standard loop for the last part and added pre_get_posts in functions.php and added the pagination but when i go to the next page, the two other sections above it disappear